# PHP and SQL foreach loop

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Im trying to set up a custom template for wordpress that retrieves the persons name and other columns from a database

```
//connect.php

<?php
global $wpdb;
$blog_id = get_current_blog_id(); 
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM database WHERE blog_id = {$blog_id}', OBJECT );
?>

//index.php
include_once "connect.php"; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM databasetablename";
//run the query
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());


foreach ($results as $result){
?>
//first person
<h2><?php echo $result -> name; ?></h2>
//second person
<h2><?php echo $result -> name; ?></h2>
//third person
<h2><?php echo $result -> name; ?></h2>

<?php
}
?>
```

But just displays the same name from the database instead of moving onto the next persons name and displaying them i think its a problem with my sql staement but in not too sure, Thanks

Comment: Can you do a var_damp of the array $results and update your question?

Comment: Do you have an example of what is in that table? (columns + some sample rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to output three times inside the loop, the `foreach` should handle every instance of the result.
Next you should check what your query actually returns.
Also you don't need to pass `OBJECT` as second parameter to `$wpdb->get_results` it is the default behaviour.

Example:

index.php

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_users";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());

foreach ($results as $result){
    print '<h2>' . $result->display_name . '</h2>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks this has worked, I'm not used to using the global connect in wordpress. There was a conflict with the sql query from the connect.php file and the one I am trying to use for the index page. That connect is for a different page on the site so I should have realised I was trying to pass sql through 2 $results